# When is a Fragment created in the Activity's onCreate accessible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I am creating & attaching a fragment in my activity onCreate method :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mSlateFragment = new SlateFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.root, mSlateFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

After that, I also setup my seekbars to their default values, to do this, I have to access the mSlateFragment object that has just been created :

```
mSlateFragment.mSlate.setProperty(33);
```

this call however provokes a crash of my app. making this call in onStart solves the crash, but is problematic since I am only setting up default values and don't want to reset them each time my activity comes to the foreground.

the mSlate object that I am trying to access is created in onCreateView of my fragment (it is a view).

Are there informations on how the lifecycles of a FragmentActivity and its fragment are intertwined ? Is there a way to make my call work ? Creating my view in the oncreate of its fragment does not seem to help either.

Comment: Here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html you can get information about Fragment Lifecycle.

Comment: the doc gives some pointers, but is a bit thin on how the different Fragment & Activity methods call themselves. I guess I will have to write a sample app with tons of logs in order to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I would cache the default values in your `SlateFragment` for 2 reasons:

1. you do not depend on the Fragments lifecycle anymore and can set them immediately after the Fragment creation
2. `onCreateView()` gets called every time the Fragment gets displayed (after a screen rotation for example), so you would loose your default values, since the View gets newly created.

Comment: yes, that's what I will do for many reasons. I am in process of migrating the Slate view from the Activity to a Fragment and this peculiarity surprised me.